# Is it possible to use Apple's payment success sound effect for my own app using AVfoundation?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

Is it possible to use apple's systemSound using AVFoundation and SystemSoundID in my production app? Do they have restrictions on their sound effects?

If possible, what is the SystemSoundID for the 'cha-ching' success sound you hear when you purchase or download something in apple's app store and authenticate using finger print or face id.

Comment: If you can't find a native solution, I'm sure there's a ton of replicas out there that you can download...

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea, the chance that Apple denies your app to the App Store because of using their sound. So maybe rethink this idea.

Comment: I wouldn't bother reusing this sound, because it is a special sound used only for purchasing products in the App Store, this would confuse users and would result in your app being rejected.

Comment: Generally, it is OK. I have apps in production that use their sound effects. There might be exceptions with certain sounds, however.

Comment: currently, It seems like there is no solid consensus regarding this topic. If it's not made for reusability in other apps why did apple bother releasing in their AVFoundation framework with SystemSoundID and made available to the public? They allow people use it in their framework and then once you try to publish it in the app store, they deny it? I don't get it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe the `SystemSoundID` you're looking for is `1407`.

Comment: And if you want vibration it's 1394.

Comment: This is amazing thank you David, I owe you a big time.